# How can a task source gain access to a Hazelcast ExecutorService without accepting tasks?

Tags: java, distributed-computing, executorservice, hazelcast

Suppose I have cluster that uses Hazelcast for communication between members and I want to provide a task execution service. Some of the cluster members are task sources (optimised for servicing requests), while others are tasks sinks (optimised for long-running computation). How can I configure task sources to have access to the service without allowing them to accept and run tasks?

Similar questions (e.g. [Can a Hazelcast ExecutorService be created to execute on a subset of the cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249431/can-a-hazelcast-executorservice-be-created-to-execute-on-a-subset-of-the-cluster)) have been answered with suggestions such as using `executeOnMembers`, but this approach requires me to implement fair load balancing and task distribution external to the ExecutorService, which defeats the purpose of using the service.

My ideal solution would be to configure the task source members with a `pool-size` of `0`, but this is invalid configuration that is rejected by the validator.

Comment: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/532 seems to be exactly what I want, but it's an open issue

Comment: @Stephan I don't think they're directly related. The ticket was / is more about to influence data distribution. You can deactivate storage on a member with the lite member setting and use MemberSelector to select lite members for execution (see full answer below :-))

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your computation members as lite members (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#enabling-lite-members) and use a MemberSelector version of `execute` or `submit` which enables automatic randomization of all selected members (a fairly simple way of load balancing but the same Hazelcast uses by default for the normal methods).

The two according methods would be http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IExecutorService.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-com.hazelcast.core.MemberSelector- and http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-com.hazelcast.core.MemberSelector-.

The MemberSelector itself is a filter interface where you can filter members based on your requirements. When you configure lite members for example as `return member.isLiteMember()` (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/Member.html#isLiteMember--). Further adjustments to the selection process can be done using additional member attributes (http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#defining-member-attributes).

If you need a more sophisticated load balancing, you'll have to do it yourself, however you already stated you don't want to implement that :)